# Using VBA to filter out empty cells in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to make a function that takes in a 1D array, filters out by empty cells, and then condenses the array and returns it.

Example: [1][2][3][""][4] returns [1][2][3][4]

I keep getting #Value! when I try to call this new array via index().

```
Function BlankRemover(ArrayToCondense As Variant) As Variant

Dim ArrayWithoutBlanks() As Variant
Dim CellsInArray As Long
Dim ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex As Long

ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex = 1

    For CellsInArray = LBound(ArrayToCondense) To UBound(ArrayToCondense)

        If ArrayToCondense(CellsInArray) <> "" Then

        ArrayWithoutBlanks(ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex) = ArrayToCondense(CellsInArray).Value

        ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex = ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex + 1

        End If

    Next CellsInArray

ReDim Preserve ArrayWithoutBlanks(LBound(ArrayToCondense) To ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex)

ArrayWithoutBlanks = Application.Transpose(ArrayWithoutBlanks)
BlankRemover = ArrayWithoutBlanks

End Function
```

Comment: Is the input array a **column** or a **row**??

Comment: Exactly what are you passing to this function?  You cannot use `ArrayWithoutBlanks` without first sizing it (which you don't do)

Comment: If you are using another array to store can't you loop the input array, test each value, if not VBNullstring/0,  redim the other array adding the value. use a counter which you increment to both redim the array you are storing in and to indicate the position to store.

Comment: I am inputting a column. Could I size it using ArrayWithoutBlanks(UBound(ArrayToCondense))? I need it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function BlankRemover(ArrayToCondense As Variant) As Variant()

Dim ArrayWithoutBlanks() As Variant
Dim CellsInArray As Variant
ReDim ArrayWithoutBlanks(1 To 1) As Variant
For Each CellsInArray In ArrayToCondense
    If CellsInArray <> "" Then
        ArrayWithoutBlanks(UBound(ArrayWithoutBlanks)) = CellsInArray
        ReDim Preserve ArrayWithoutBlanks(1 To UBound(ArrayWithoutBlanks) + 1)
    End If
Next CellsInArray

ArrayWithoutBlanks = Application.Transpose(ArrayWithoutBlanks)
BlankRemover = Application.Transpose(ArrayWithoutBlanks)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

### Notes:

1. You should define `BlankRemover` as an array: `Variant()`
2. `.Value` not needed at end of `ArrayToCondense(CellsInArray)`

**The code:**

```
Function BlankRemover(ArrayToCondense As Variant) As Variant()

Dim ArrayWithoutBlanks() As Variant
Dim CellsInArray As Long
Dim ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex As Long

ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex = 0

    For CellsInArray = LBound(ArrayToCondense) To UBound(ArrayToCondense)

        If ArrayToCondense(CellsInArray) <> "" Then

        ReDim Preserve ArrayWithoutBlanks(ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex)

        ArrayWithoutBlanks(ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex) = ArrayToCondense(CellsInArray)

        ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex = ArrayWithoutBlanksIndex + 1

        End If

    Next CellsInArray

    'ArrayWithoutBlanks = Application.Transpose(ArrayWithoutBlanks)
    BlankRemover = ArrayWithoutBlanks

End Function 'BlankRemover
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared the function

```
Function BlankRemover(ArrayToCondense As Variant) As Variant
```

so that `ArrayToCondense` is not an array, to make it an array you switch `ArrayToCondense` with `ArrayToCondense()` so the final code will be:

```
Function BlankRemover(ArrayToCondense As Variant) As Variant()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code itself. Make the new array initially equal to the size of the original array; then do one "ReDim Preserve" at the end. Also, don't use a value like "1", arrays can have multiple starting indices. Here's what the code would ideally look like for doing this with *arrays* (though as I'll note below, I don't think that's actually what you want):

```
Function blankRemover(arr As Variant) As Variant

    If Not IsArray(arr) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    ReDim newArr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = LBound(arr)

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Not arr(i) = "" Then
            newArr(j) = arr(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve newArr(LBound(arr) To j - 1)
    blankRemover = newArr

End Function
```

But based on your comments, it sounds like you're not actually passing this function an array: you're passing it a range. So you'd actually want to use something like this:

```
Function blankRemoverRng(rng As Range) As Variant

    If Not ((rng.Rows.Count = 1) Xor (rng.Columns.Count = 1)) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = narrow2dArray(rng.Value)

    ReDim newArr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = LBound(arr)

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Not arr(i) = "" Then
            newArr(j) = arr(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve newArr(LBound(arr) To j - 1)
    blankRemoverRng = newArr

End Function
Function narrow2dArray(ByRef arr As Variant, Optional ByVal newBase As Long = 1) As Variant
'Takes a 2d array which has one dimension of size 1 and converts it to a 1d array with base newBase
'IE it takes an array with these dimensions:
    'Dim arr(1 To 10, 1 To 1)
'And turns it into an array with these dimensions:
    'Dim arr(1 To 10)

    On Error GoTo exitStatement
    Dim bigDim As Integer
    If Not IsArray(arr) Then
        Dim smallArr(1 To 1) As Variant
        smallArr(1) = arr
        narrow2dArray = smallArr
        Exit Function
    ElseIf LBound(arr, 1) = UBound(arr, 1) Then
        bigDim = 2
    ElseIf LBound(arr, 2) = UBound(arr, 2) Then
        bigDim = 1
    Else
        GoTo exitStatement
    End If

    ReDim tempArr(newBase To UBound(arr, bigDim) - LBound(arr, bigDim) + newBase) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = LBound(arr, bigDim)
    If bigDim = 2 Then
        For i = LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr)
            If IsObject(arr(1, j)) Then
                Set tempArr(i) = arr(1, j)
            Else
                tempArr(i) = arr(1, j)
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Next
    Else
        For i = LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr)
            If IsObject(arr(j, 1)) Then
                Set tempArr(i) = arr(j, 1)
            Else
                tempArr(i) = arr(j, 1)
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Next
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    narrow2dArray = tempArr
    Exit Function

exitStatement:
    MsgBox "Error: One of array's dimensions must have size = 1"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Stop

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are coming later looking for a simple answer:

```
Filter(arrayElement, "", False)
```